# Is the subpanel installation in a detached garage correctly done?

Tags: electrical-panel

I have a small subpanel next to my main house panel with only 4 slots. I am out of breaker spaces, so I've routed 8 gauge wiring (2-120V split phase, 1-nuetral and 1 ground) to the new sub-panel. Very short run of less than 6 feet of wiring between the panels.

I have filled only two slots with a ganged 30 amp breaker in the sub-panel that I need for some testing equipment in my garage (both panels and in a detached garage). I will likely put 2 additional 15 amp breakers in the future in the sub-panel. I have tied all 8 awg wires into the main busses.

Neutral and ground are bonded, but I've run separate wires to the bonded bus. I believe this is a very conservative, safe installation, but is it code, or even good practice? The 8 gauge wiring is ultimately protected by the main disconnect breaker (200 amps) since I've tied to the buss directly, but the voltage drop in only 1-2 volts, so even a direct short should not overheat the wiring.

I don't have any spare slots in the main panel to install a ganged 50 amp breaker - would like to do that, but just don't have the space. I guess I could pull two existing 15 amp breakers, install the ganged 50 amp and reroute the existing services to the new 15 amp breakers in the sub-panel - and I can do that if the only safe installation.

Should I re-wire or not?

Comment: *but the voltage drop in only 1-2 volts, so even a direct short should not overheat the wiring.* this is really a scary level of **not understanding** - in the case of a direct short, you'll be dropping 240V and those wires will literally be on fire.

Answer (score 4):

So, you have 8 gauge wire potentially subject to a fault current of up to 200 amps without anything tripping. You also have the neutral and ground bonded in a sub-panel (despite running separate neutral and ground wires to it, so bonding in the sub-panel is a puzzling choice in itself, as well as being a violation.) [or else possibly you have written unclearly about what you have done with the ground and neutral?]

Wrong. Just....wrong.

Pull two breakers, insert a 50 A breaker, and move the 15A circuits to the sub. And unbond/isolate the neutral and ground in the sub. Get a different/larger sub-panel if you need additional circuits (or give a long hard look at a complete panel replacement with adequate spaces in the main panel - not all that expensive if the incoming service is adequate, but attached to a panel with few spaces.)

If your panel is listed for them breakers with two separate 15A circuits in a single space breaker are another option to make space.

Comment: I certainly stand corrected - after a quick estimate of expected temperature rise combined with trip times vrs fault current of (Siemens Residential) common circuit breakers it becomes very obvious that the 8 awg wiring is woefully inadequate - and length is not the determinant!  The breaker re-arrangement is a necessity.  BTW, the "bonding" is in the main panel only, with the ground rod directly below the main panel.

Answer (score 3):

Your installation is **NOT** code compliant.

If you want to tap directly off the 200 ampere bus bars, your conductors will have to be sized to carry 200 amperes. #8 is nowhere near large enough. You're going to have to figure out a way to install a double pole 50 ampere breaker to protect the 8 AWG feeders, or install 3/0 copper feeders instead.

I'm not even sure if you're allowed to tap directly off the ungrounded (hot) bus bars, I'd have to read through the code to find out. However, I suspect it may not be allowed.

The grounded (neutral) and grounding bus bars in the secondary panel **must** be separated. The grounded (neutral) bus should be isolated, while the grounding bar and the enclosure should be bonded.